# What are the teachings of Sri Gorakhnath?

Tags: yoga, teaching, nath

[Gorakhnath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorakhnath) is a famous yogi from the Nath sampradaya. He is also known as Goraksha natha.

What were his main teachings?

And, besides the [Goraksha Samhita](https://www.amazon.in/Goraksha-Samhita-Also-Known-Paddhati-ebook/dp/B00QTCGI7W), what are the other main works by him?